# Setting Value with Loop on Rownum = 1 VS Select Into with Exception

Tags: oracle, plsql, rownum

I couldn't find an answer, so either it doesn't exist or I failed to find the magic combination of words to search for.

Which of the following is more efficient, and why?

(1) Loop on Rownum = 1

```
function get_a_val(limit_var in varchar2) is
  return_var table_name.data_col%type;
begin
  for rec in (select data_col, extra_col1, extra_col2 
              from table_name 
                where some_col = limit_var
                  and rownum   = 1)
  loop
    return_var := data_col;
  end loop;
  return(return_var);
end get_a_val;
```

(2) Select Into with Exception

```
function get_a_val(limit_var in varchar2) is
  return_var table_name.data_col%type;
begin
  select data_col into return_var 
  from table_name 
    where some_col = limit_var
      and rownum   = 1;
  return(return_var);
exception
  when no_data_found then return null;
end get_a_val;
```

Comment: did you check compare explain plans ?

Comment: Why is this important?

Comment: There are some similar questions I think, but why not do some investigation and performance testing yourself?

Comment: In either case I'd reformat the code to make sure the entire query can be seen easily - here the `ROWNUM = 1` runs off the edge of the text box. If you go with #1 I'd comment the code to make it clear that you're intentionally only retrieving the first row from the cursor.

Comment: You can have a look at [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-nov/o68plsql-088608.html)

Comment: No idea what a compare explain plan is. This question is important because I see the first option everywhere at work and the user base has a need for optimized runtime wherever possible. I have had no luck finding the answer anywhere so far. I was hoping for a deep-down, behind-the-scenes explanation of what Oracle does to make one faster than the other. When I originally posted this I had no idea how to yest things like this, but I think I might be able to try. Nitish that was very helpful info! Not exactly what I need but it definitely helps.